# Proving a class satisfies axioms of ZF-C

Tags: set-theory

We were given an exercise, to prove that for every regular $\theta$, the class $\{x||tc(x)|<\theta\}$ satisfies ZF-C without the powerset axiom. We ran into some difficulties proving the replacement axiom.

So, assuming all elements of the range are in $H_\theta$, we have no problem. But what guarantees us that this is the case? Can we nor work with functions that send elements in $H_\theta$ out of range?

Comment: What does ZF-C mean? It's either ZFC or ZF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The axiom schema of replacement (e.g. as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_replacement)) only applies to those $\phi$ such that for all $x$ we can find a unique $y$ such that $\phi(x,y)$ holds (omitting parameters $w_i$ for simplicity). This $y$ must thus exist and be unique in the model $V$ we are considering (so in particular it must be in $V$ or $H_\theta$), or we don't even need to consider this $\phi$.

Comment: It's basically a refomulation of what Arthur said, but maybe a reformulation makes it clearer for you?

Comment: Thanks, we were simply using a formulation of what formula satisfies the function property, that is incorrect when working with several models.